# Refresh div on parent page from iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, html, parent

I'm using fancybox's modal box with an iFrame. On form success from the iFrame I'm using the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout('window.top.location.href = "/page.asp"; ',999);
</script>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
setTimeout("parent.$.fancybox.close();",1000)
//-->
</script>
```

This closes fancybox's modal box and refreshes the parent page. I want to target a div to refresh on the parent page from the iFrame using Jquery.

I want the target DIV on the parent page with the id="target" to refresh, NOT the entire page. How do I go about it using JQuery?

TIA

Code Example below

Parent Page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="target">
content content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

iFrame Page Upon Form Validation

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout('window.top.location.href = "/parent_page.asp"; ',999);
</script>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
setTimeout("parent.$.fancybox.close();",1000)
//-->
</script>
```

How do I make a function on the parent page to refresh the div id="target" and call it from the iFrame. Right now, the entire parent page refreshes.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example with some example HTML including a DIV and a concrete description of what you want to "refresh" and what effect "refreshing" needs to have for you? I suspect what you want is to reload the page in AJAX, pass the new HTML to jQuery, and use `.remove()` and `.html(new_html)` the new DIV contents into the existing DIV.

Comment: I tried Googling a solution using what you mentioned to no avail. How would I go about doing this exactly using AJAX ?

Answer (score 3):

Pass the second parameter to jQuery, with the desired scope

Replace `window.setTimeout('window.top.location.href = "/page.asp"; ',999);` with this:

```
window.setTimeOut(function(){
    $("#target", window.parent).load("/page.asp #target");
},999);
```

Comment: I'm a complete jQuery novice. Please include code example for parent and iframe page along with complete script syntax. Code snippets alone aren't enough

Comment: Edited my answer, is this what you want?

Comment: I tried Andre's solution but it did not work. The fancybox closed and then the parent window came into focus but the content of the div did not change.  Am I missing something in the page to make this work? From what I read, I need to make a function in the parent page and call it from the iFrame.

Comment: I do  have other DIV's within the target DIV. I was under the impression that all within the target DIV would refresh

Comment: For the fancybox to work, I had to create a function on the parent page using $(document).ready(function() {function triggerClose(){
   var el = $("#fancyCloseId");
   el.bind("click", $.fn.fancybox.close);
   el.trigger('click'); 
  }  and then call the function from the iframe

Comment: i tried livequery jQuery plugin and that didnt work. this can't be this hard.

Comment: And it's not... Do you use any tools to see if the ajax request is being made? And also, switch "/page.asp #target" to "/page.asp"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by calling a javascript function in parent page from the page contained in iframe.

```
window.parent.myFunctionInParent('my param');
```

You can learn the technique step by step in [How to refresh parent page partially from page within iframe](http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2011/07/refresh-parent-page-partially-from.html).

Hope this helps.