# Reload div on parent page from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm making a small application, but I ran into a problem. Basically, I have a page which consists of header and an iframe. Application itself runs in the iframe, while header stays the same, but here's the thing. Header displays some data from database which is updated from the application. In order for data in the header to stay up to date, I need to refresh it on button click from iframe. So my question is - is it possible? Is it possible to reload a div element in parent page from iframe? 
All I have fro now is this jQuery:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function()
     $('#stats').load('reload.php');
}, 5000);
```

Which reloads my div every 5 seconds, but I don't know if it's a good idea to reload a div automatically after a period of time. Well, I hope you guys understand my problem. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refresh div on parent page from iframe using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155714/refresh-div-on-parent-page-from-iframe-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent window (=main window) from the iframe, not a problem.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <iframe src="myFrame.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

myFrame.htm:

```
<script>
    parent.document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = "whatever you want";
</script>
```

If you want, you can do ajax requests and everything else you need, as long as the some origin policy is not violated (domains, ports & protocols must match).

Comment: Oh, thank you! Seems like this will do the trick. Didn't know the answer was that simple, but, then again, I'm still a novice at JavaScript. :)